# How can I convert a png file scraped into bytes using any python image library, built in or third party

Tags: python-3.x, byte, png

The following is a scraped png image from a site. I want its size in bytes, not the dimensions. (I'm not an expert with images and I seem confuse the two terms.) Here's what I did after scraping the image called "imone".

```
import io
imone = io.BytesIO()
```

When I call it by name, I get

```
<io.Bytes at 0x7fdf040a16d0>
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

For correct terms: You want ***total bytes length*** (also called ***byte-size***).

Anyways no Python here to test but...

> *Here's what I did after scraping the image called "imone"*

You mean `imone` already contains the PNG data **before** you do this line `imone = io.BytesIO()`??

If yes, then you could try:

```
imone = here your scrapped PNG image bytes??

imsize = len(imone) # Get bytes length
print "Byte size: " % imsize
```

Option #2: Maybe just try a different way:

```
import os

imgURL = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/photos/image.png' #Your scraped image url
imgSIZE = os.path.getsize(imgURL) # Get bytes length
print "Byte size: " % imgSIZE
```

**Edit**: Since you mention Selenium, I don't use it, but you can try like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

imone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath")
imgURL = imone.get_attribute('src') #Your scraped image url path
imgSIZE = os.path.getsize(imgURL) # Get bytes length
print "Byte size: " % imgSIZE
```

Comment: VC One, I'm very eager to try this. I wanted file size, like when you view a file like an image locally you find it's lets say 5kb which is also 5000 bytes...that's the kind of size I'm talking about. I'm still trying to figure a way out 5 days now. I hope I'll be successful, I'll also be happy to tell you it worked for me. Let me get to work then.

Comment: I was using selenium with Python, so wrote........imone =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath")

Comment: @Minyae If still not working then try the new **edit** code. Otherwise just [**update your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45219319/edit) giving example page like Wikipedia and show us a full testable code for one image scraping. If we know & test what you did then easier to advise quickly...

Comment: One, got you. Here's what's happenig, the images I'm scrapping belong to visual captcha and therefore their src is dynamic with every reload/session...at least the last bit of it. If I provide the src upto to the static point which is unique to every image do you think the browser will return the first image that wins? The one whose src is close to what I'm specifying? eg. they are five images and are indexed from 0 to 4 and the difference in these five integers appears in the src. With every reload, everything upto these numbers stays the same, and the rest from those five numbers doesn,t

Comment: also, today I've been thinking; what code does a browser use to give us image file size? If you view image info in Firefox you'll find it's dimensions and file size. What's behind that...I was hoping to incorporate that into my code..how do you like that idea, mh?

Comment: I was also thinking of injecting java-script to get me the file size...

Comment: You see a browser e.g. Firefox already loads the image and my belief is that the image exists within the browser, that's why one is able to right-click and get file size. Why can't I implement the same code...and get the file size in my program?

Comment: _"what code does a browser use to give us image file size?"_ when you give an image URL the browser makes a request for image's bytes to server of image. The browser knows how many bytes it received for this file and it tells you if you check by _"right-click and get file size"_. You can achieve same thing with `imgSIZE = os.path.getsize(imgURL)`...

Comment: PS: How do you know about _"the src up to the static point which is unique to every image"_? Are you checking the html page's source code (text)? If yes, why not just load the same text into Python and just extract path text directly from that section? If the URL in HTML was `<img src="www.site.com/image.png">` then extract text from `"www` ..up to next hit of.. `"` so that now your final extract text is `www.site.com/image.png`. If you put this extract as `imgURL = your extracted path text` then you could do `imgSIZE = os.path.getsize(imgURL)`...

Comment: VC; thnks 4 coming all this way with me. I view page source, rightclick on the first visualcaptcha n see somthng like this "www.xyz.com/Plugins/VisualCaptcha/Handler.ashx/image/0?namespace=8d3ff=gtfgnn1b82". The src of the first visual -captcha is unique 2 itself ONLY because of the "0" before the "?" which's also b4 "namespace". The nxt captcha has a 1, then 2. Evething btwn the 2 "=" is the same even if u log in with a difft acc. Evthing after the 2nd "=" sign is the same for every captcha in the same page load event but dift if u reload, n is also difft the nxt time u or some1 else logs in.